# Find control in grid view control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know there are alot of questions&answers about this but non of them works for me

Trying to populate this Drop Down List via a function in code behind:

This drop down list is for Images names, when a user choose one and clicks the "Update" link button in the Grid View I need to insert a suffix to the image name (for the path),
so if the user choose an image name from the list the update button it will actually update the fileName + insert at the beginning the path, so it would be

> ../images/gary.jpg

for the name gary.

> aspx page

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
                <EditItemTemplate>                      
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlImages" runat="server">
                        <Items>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Choose" Value="" />
                        </Items>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                ...
```

> code behind

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddlImages = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlImages") as DropDownList);
            ShowImages(ddlImages);

        }
}
```

"ddlImages" is null, how can I find him?

---

Managed to find the drop down list like that:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                DropDownList ddlImages = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlImages");
                ddlImages.DataSource = GetImages();
                ddlImages.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Now i am facing another problem, in the aspx i have an "UpdateCommand" which take parameters and try to update the database. The problem- it need to take the dropDownList chosen value but instead it take: "" how can i change it to take the value that the user choose in the dropDownList

> aspx page

```
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [investigator] SET [name] = @name, [area] = @area, [country] = @country,     [picture] = @picture, [review] = @review WHERE [Id] = @Id">

 <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="area" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="country" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="picture" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="review" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
```

Meaning- I have to change

```
<asp:Parameter Name="picture" Type="String" />
```

to drop down list selected value. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You are trying to get the Dropdown list in the RowDataBoud Event. But the Dropdown list is in EditItemTemplate, so you can get the Dropdown only in the edit mode of the row.

Comment: @Kiran Hegde, managed to do that. now i am facing another problem, in the aspx i have an "UpdateCommand" which take parameters and try to update the database. The problem- it need to take the dropDownList chosen value but instead it take: "<asp:Parameter Name="picture" Type="String" />" how can i change it to take the value that the user choose in the dropDownList

Comment: Can you Show the aspx source code of the data source with updatecommand?

Comment: @Kiran Hegde,  updated the question.

Comment: Can you check the answer if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your question about the update Parameter, you should use the ControlParameter instead of general Parameter. Try replacing the Parameter Definition for the Dropdown list with following 
code.

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="picture" ControlID="ddlImages" 
    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
```

**UPDATE**
What you can do as alternate is,

Change the parameter back to

```
<asp:Parameter Name="picture" Type="String" />
```

Add RowUpdating event handler to the gridview
In the RowUpdating command set the data source parameter based on the selected value as below

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
DropDownList ddlImages=  row.FindControl("ddlImages") as DropDownList;
SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["picture"].DefaultValue = ddlImages.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error: "Could not find control 'ddlImages' in ControlParameter 'picture'."

Comment: found that I have to use the dollar char ($) to access the inner control, ControlID="dvEmployee$ddlDept" , but I don't know how to reflect it in my code.

Comment: can you check the above answer

Comment: where should I place it?

Comment: GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]; -<"RowIndex" showing an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'RowIndex'

Comment: It is working for me. Dont you see e.RowIndex in the RowUpdating event?

Comment: no, i understood why: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/567531/WhyplusRows-bpluse-RowIndex-dplusplusplusIsplusU

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57205/discussion-between-kiran-hegde-and-user2487126).